# Empty Eclipse Run Configuration File

Tags: eclipse, debugging, xdebug

While trying to setup Debug Configuration to debug my php project on Eclipse Java IDE for Web Developers, Eclipse Juno. There is no option to select the index.php. This is confusing because it is not even showing any files from the current workspace. Attached snapshot will explain further.
[image: Empty Debug Configuration Select File]
This is not letting me run the debugger, any clues here would be helpful.
Thanks.

Comment: It looks like you don't have any 'PHP Project' since this dialog will show php projects only.

Comment: I checkout my projects from Subversive as a new project. How would I get them as Php projects.

Comment: Try right-click the project > Configure > Add PHP support

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Atlanto suggested
"It looks like you don't have any 'PHP Project' since this dialog will show php projects only."

Thats the correct answer, Eclipse checks out projects directly and it may not check them out as Php projects. Hence make sure when checking out projects from Subversive to chose the 2nd option **Find/Checkout** as and then checkout them as a **New Project** using the wizard so they are checked out under the Php perspective and then can show under debug configuration.

Comment: I had the same problem and your solution is fine. For the record, I changed an existing directory to PHP Project with right click on the folder -> configure -> add php support and got it work.